# i am trying to extract date from text using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the date from this '2025-03-21T12:54:41Z' text using python regular expression.

```
date=re.match('(\d{4})[/.-](\d{2})[/.-](\d{2})$', date[0])
print(date)
```

This give output as None

also, I tried this code

```
date_reg_exp = re.compile('\d{4}(?P<sep>[-/])\d{2}(?P=sep)\d{2}')
matches_list=date_reg_exp.findall(date[0])
for match in matches_list:
  print match
```

This gives output as - only

Please help

Comment: You should use `datetime.datetime.strptime` to parse instead of regex

Comment: Your first one won't work because you used `$`, which means the end of the string. And the second, you're only grouping on and printing the separators

Comment: As @cricket_007 said, $ matches the end. If you want to match the beginning, use ^ instead:  date= re.match('^(\d{4})[/.-](\d{2})[/.-](\d{2})', date[0])

Comment: @Hai Vu already tried datetime.datetime.strptime but it is not working

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks man it worked.I had no idea that so many standards exist to store time.

Comment: Welcome, but honestly, what's wrong with `date[0].split("T")[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is wrong because it has a `$` at the end. `$` asserts that this is the end of the string.

The regex engine matches your string with the regex and after matching the last two digits, expects a `$` - end of the string. However, your string still has `T12:54:41Z` before the end, so the regex does not match.

To fix this, remove `$`:

```
>>> re.match('(\d{4})[/.-](\d{2})[/.-](\d{2})', '2025-03-21T12:54:41Z')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='2025-03-21'>
```

Comment: strptime doesn't work as expected. See marked duplicate in comments

Comment: @cricket_007 Got it. Deleted now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  using `$` sigil at the end of your regexp, which is matching end-of-line character, try using `^` at the beginning:

```
import re
date='2025-03-21T12:54:41Z'
date=re.match('^(\d{4})[/.-](\d{2})[/.-](\d{2})', date)
print(date)
```

Output in python3:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='2025-03-21'>
```

Python2:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fd191ac1ae0>
```